# AngularJS - Shop list best practice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-components

I'm new to AngularJS, and i'm want to know what's the best and easiest practices to do this simple shop list application.

So this is my shop:
[image]

I got three servers in my select input. Each server got own list of items, displayed in another component.

I'm thinking about creating routes with variables like `localhost:4200/shop/{server1}` which gonna show my list of items based on url path. Select option will just change path in my application to show shop list for specific server.

Is it a good practice, or there is better and easier solution to implement this simple shop application?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if filtering data with routing is a good practice with Angular, I can say that it is not a bad one. Here's a link to the official Angular documentation about routing : [Angular - Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router)

But if you're asking if it is the only way to filter data or spread parameters, the answer is clearly **no**. Angular projects are SPA (Single Page Application), so you can do everything without touching the url.

For a quick example, you can attach a `(click)` event on your elements that display the shop list you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use just one component and three different click events to display three different results. One component can work in your case. Using a router and routing logic for your requirement will be a costly affair. Your user will have a better application feel if these are covered in just one component and with three different click events.